# Как передать класс в метод и создать екземпляр класса?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Доброе время суток, на старом, добром Objective-C можно было создать метод, и передать класс:

```
- (void)setClass:(Class)aClass {
    NSObject *object = [[aClass alloc] init];
}
```

Вызов метода (User унаследован от NSObject):

```
[self setClass:[User class]];
```

Каким образом можно повторить эти же действия на Apple Swift (как я не крутил и не мучал, ничего не получилось, вся надежда на Вас)?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
func funcion(object: NSObject) {
   let typeOfObject = object.dynamicType
   var freshInstance = typeOfObject()
}
```

Comment: @Ковальский

Спасибо Вам большое! Это решило мою проблему!

Comment: @dev_nikita_ysacov

Не за что!

Answer (score 2):

Так, как вы делали раньше, нельзя. Но это всё равно был хак.

На swift'е правильно делать такое через [generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_234):

```
func do<T>()
{
    T t = T()
    // можно работать с T дальше
}
```

Вызов:

```
self.do<User>()
```

Comment: @VladD

Большое спасибо Вам за помощь, но приведенный Вами код не компилируеться :(

Comment: @dev_nikita_ysacov: У меня под рукой нет компилятора. А какое сообщение об ошибке?